# <p:dataTable> com quantidade de colunas variável

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Boa noite.

Alguém sabe dizer se é possível (e como fazê-lo) criar um dataTable do primefaces cujo número de colunas seja variável?

Por exemplo, imagine dois casos, A e B. No conjunto A eu criaria 3 colunas. Já no B, eu criaria apenas 2.

Grato!

Answer (score 2):

O primefaces tem o componente `<p:columns>`.

Segue o link para o showcase [aqui](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml)

Comment: Rafael, respostas muito curtas ou somente com links costumam ser um pouco mal vistas pela comunidade, afinal a informação pode não acrescentar muito e o link pode deixar de existir. Se possível, sugiro acrescentar mais algumas informações, talvez um pequeno exemplo com código para ilustrar o uso da tag `columns`.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário, isso me ajudou bastante! :)

Comment: @utluiz♦ Tudo bem, como o link é odo showcase oficial do primefaces e lá contem um exemplo pensei ser desnecessário um novo exemplo.